# setlocale/strftime issue

Tags: php, localization

I am using the following to output the full name of a month in Greek.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'el_GR');
strftime("%B");
```

This works, except the output string is ISO-8859-7 (greek code page), which is a problem since I need a UTF-8 string. I could put this through iconv to convert it, but I was wondering if there was a way to do that without resorting to an extra function.

Could you somehow tell strftime to output a UTF-8 string in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'el_GR.UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a sidenote to [ZZ Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149808/zz-coder)'s answer:

if `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'el_GR.UTF-8');`

does **not work in linux**, check your enabled locales by running `locale -a` from the shell.

If you don't see `el_GR.UTF-8` there, open `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the corresponding line.

Then run `locale-gen` and you should be ok.